# Delete certificate object from smart card with NCRYPT_CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY

Tags: c#, cryptography, smartcard, cng

I am trying to use NCRYPT_CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY (flag for NCryptSetProperty) to create and delete certificate object on smartcard.

There is a way to delete only the certificate object with NCryptSetProperty and NCRYPT_CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY and not using NCryptDeleteKey that deletes the keys and certificates objects?

Comment: The certificate contains the key so why do you need the certificate with a different key?

Comment: I don't need the certificate, I only need the keys object without the certificate object, so I want to delete the certificate object without deleting the keys objects

Comment: what happens when in windows you try to open the certificate in windows.  Doesn't windows use the certificate to unlock the card?